# Free up serial port after SerialException 'Access is Denied' to reconnect

Tags: windows, python-2.7, serial-port, pyserial, access-denied

I have a simple class Connect that creates a serial connection upon instantiation.

```
import serial
import serial.tools.list_ports_windows as list_ports

class Connect:
    def __init__(self):
        connect(self)

    def connect(self):
        self.ser = serial.Serial(port='COM1')

    def disconnect(self):
        self.ser.close()

    def __del__(self):
        self.disconnect()
        del self.ser
```

If I create an instance of this class and then destroy my instance in such a way that neither the disconnect() nor the **del**() method runs, the port will still be tied up. So if I try to connect again I get the following exception:

```
SerialException: could not open port 'COM1': WindowsError(5, 'Access is denied.')
```

What can I do with my code to disconnect the serial port, so I can reconnect to it with a new instance of Connect?